# Passing extra values to stripe using react with react-stripe-elements - not working

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments

the developer responsible for for the front-end development and stripe integration has bailed on the project so I'm trying my best to understand how react works and fix stripe's paymentintent creation so that we can launch the project for the client.

Please note that before this incident I had no experience with React, and only basic knowledge of JavaScript in general.

**The Problem:** The payment intent does not include extra data from the **metadata** or **owner** dictionaries. Below you can find the response I get when I authorise and create a test payment:

```
[30/Dec/2019 09:14:38] "POST /payment-stripe/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
{'Content-Length': '1849', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Host': '529c6eef.ngrok.io', 'User-Agent': 'Stripe/1.0 (+https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)', 'Connection': 'close', 'Accept': '*/*; q=0.5, application/xml', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Stripe-Signature': 't=1577693707,v1=f43e4c1ecf91a8b513gseg453gsetrgg578d9df8d9c5aa6f9720edb9d973eef5,v0=ad2feb2527afde9521816f7bebsstbsteb3233743df0555720c6d971f6d5a7', 'X-Forwarded-For': '54.187.174.169'}
{
  "amount": 1300,
  "amount_capturable": 0,
  "amount_received": 0,
  "application": null,
  "application_fee_amount": null,
  "canceled_at": null,
  "cancellation_reason": null,
  "capture_method": "automatic",
  "charges": {
    "data": [],
    "has_more": false,
    "object": "list",
    "total_count": 0,
    "url": "/v1/charges?payment_intent=pi_1FvJP4E8otG6IyHyLyzB5Xyh"
  },
  "client_secret": "pi_MY_CLIENT_SECRET",
  "confirmation_method": "automatic",
  "created": 1577693706,
  "currency": "eur",
  "customer": null,
  "description": null,
  "id": "pi_1FvJP4E8otG6IyHyLyzB5Xyh",
  "invoice": null,
  "last_payment_error": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {},
  "next_action": null,
  "object": "payment_intent",
  "on_behalf_of": null,
  "payment_method": null,
  "payment_method_options": {
    "card": {
      "installments": null,
      "request_three_d_secure": "automatic"
    }
  },
  "payment_method_types": [
    "ideal"
  ],
  "receipt_email": null,
  "review": null,
  "setup_future_usage": null,
  "shipping": null,
  "source": null,
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
  "status": "requires_payment_method",
  "transfer_data": null,
  "transfer_group": null
}
```

In the response you can see that the extra owner data or metadata that I have declared (as seen below) don't get passed to the webhook. Here is the code for the checkout:

```
    if (this.state.paymentType === 'ideal') {
      const idealBank = this.props.elements.getElement('idealBank');
      const content = await response.json();
      if (this.props.stripe) {
        this.props.stripe
          .createSource({
            type: 'ideal',
            amount: this.props.event.stock[0].price * 100,
            currency: 'eur',
            // quantity: this.props.amount,
            service_fee: this.props.event.stock[0].price,
            stock_type: this.props.event.stock[0].id,
            // stock_type: this.props.event.stock[this.state.parkIndex].id,

            event: this.props.event.id,
            owner: {
              // name: 'test'
              first_name: this.first_name.value,
              last_name: this.last_name.value,
              phonenumber: this.phonenumber.value,
              email: this.email.value
            },
            redirect: {
              return_url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/payment-succeeded/'
            },
            metadata: {
              first_name: this.first_name.value,
              last_name: this.last_name.value,
              phonenumber: this.phonenumber.value,
              email: this.email.value
            }
          })
           // EDIT: I'VE ADDED THIS AS RECOMMENDED IN THE COMMENTS:
          .then(response => response)

          .then(
            this.props.stripe.confirmIdealPayment(content.client_secret, {
              payment_method: {
                ideal: idealBank
              },
              return_url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/payment-succeeded/',
            }),
          );
```

I tried to find what goes wrong by following the react-stripe-elements docs here: https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements but could not find what went wrong.

I also checked if the payment intent data passed is correct by following the stripe guidelines: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object .

While the request works and the webhooks get created and sent successfully the owner:{} and metadata:{} are not in the request.

I need the extra data to be passed with the webhooks so that I can validate the payments in the back-end I have created.

**Why does the extra data I declare not pass along with the rest of the data in the request?**

I would appreciate anyone taking a look and I'm looking forward to your recommendations, comments and answers.

Thank you!

Comment: Tony, Although you are creating a `source` with all these `owner` and `metadata` information, but the `source` you created is **NOT** used to complete the payment_intent, instead, you are just confirming the payment_intent with `idealBank ` element. 
So to get these information, you should confirmIdealPayment with the source ID you've created `this.props.stripe.confirmIdealPayment(content.client_secret, {
              payment_method: source.id ....`

Comment: hey @wsw , I have tried a few things here and there. But now my page does not redirect. Where and how am I supposed to include the source? I have updated my question with the missing part (confirmIdealPayment)

Comment: Tony, acutally have you tried this `this.props.stripe.createSource({...}).then(result => {return this.props.stripe.confirmIdealPayment(content.client_secret, {payment_method:result.source.id})`

Here, basically you are passing the created source.id to the `confirmIdealPayment` function.